# How to accept call(voice) using key event in android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, phone-call

I am developing an application in that I want to accept incoming call automatically after few seconds. I tried lot of codes using telephony manager,Intent but nothing is working in 5.0. The below code is working fine when my application is open. but in my application in background the code is not working.

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "input keyevent " + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK );
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {

            // do something proper here.
        }
    }
}).start();
```

please any one help me in this I am using Thread for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to register a receiver for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` and implement a `PhoneStateListener`

Comment: can you explain little bit more sorry

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create a class named `CallReceiver` that extends `BroadcastReceiver`

implement `onReceive` and instantiate a `PhoneStateListener`

you need to implement and handle such listener, e.g. look at [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html)

you can hangup when you receive `CALL_STATE_RINGING`

Comment: Thanks for the Answer sherpya. Have you tested this in Lollipop because it showing some error when accessing the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission